# MS Access importing UTF-8 file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I import several '|' separated files to my DB with this:

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim path1 As String

path1 = "C:\ImportFiles"

Destination = "C:\ImportFiles\processed"

Set fs = Application.FileSearch

With fs
    .LookIn = Path1
    .FileName = "*.*"
    If .Execute > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count

            DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImportRPS", "tbImportRPSTemp", .FoundFiles(i), False
            fileName = .FoundFiles(i)
            fileName = Replace(fileName, path1, "")

            Set fs1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            fs1.MoveFile Path1 & fileName, Destination & Format(Now, "YYYYDDMMTHHMMSS") & fileName

        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "No files to update", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Problem is, the files are in UTF-8 while the access database I'm working with is not, it imports with 'ï»¿' in front of the first record and my table ends looking like this:

```
Type    Nmbr    Date
ï»¿100  12312   15082013
```

What can I do to import the files whitout problem? Is it possible to convert the file to ANSI and them import it or are there better ways? I can't do it manually because those files are supposed to arrive by the dozens every day.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx the last parameter of TransferText is the code page. In windows UTF-8 is code page 65001.

So, try adding `, , 65001` to your DoCmd.TransferText line. I think it should look like:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImportRPS", "tbImportRPSTemp", .FoundFiles(i), False, , 650001
```

I don't have the ability to test this code right now, but I believe it should work.

Comment: It's not working, double checked it and the code page is 65001, don't know what is the problem.

Comment: I tested it on my machine with Access 2010. I got it working fine. My guess is it has something to do with your input specification, "InputRPS". Try leaving the input specification blank, or create a new one that is set to UTF-8 (in the advanced section of the inport text dialog), or create a schema.ini file.

Comment: There is a typo in that suggested line, the codepage in the line shows 650001, should be 65001.